# asp.net mvc 3: best way manage a model with an image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, image, model, upload

I'm trying to find the best way to manage a model with an associated image.

I don't know if is better to persiste the image in data store

```
class MyModel {
  ...
  public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

or save the Url and upload the image to filesystem

```
class MyModel {
  ...
  public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

The essential thing is that I want manage the image in when I'm creating or editing the model record.

I don't want a dedicated model/view/controller aimed to upload/persist the image to the server. I want manage the imaged linked to a specific entity in the db.

Regards,
Giacomo

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is fine because you're storing the image in the database. You will still need a helper function of some sort which generates a URL to a handler which renders/displays the image.

You could choose to **also** store the image url in which case you wouldn't necessarily need a helper method.

*If you would be storing images outside the database* (e.g. on the filesystem) you wouldn't need the `ImageData` byte field obviously...

Comment: @giacomo: Glad that helped, however it is a bit offtopic if i look at your question...

Comment: It helped me in using a different approach. I use clientside js to post files and a controller to save the file to server fs, than I can associate MyModel.ImageUrl with the filename.

Comment: For being 100% clear I'd like to have a similar result that I've in Ruby on Rails with using Paperclip Gem (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). It treats and attachment as any other field in a model.